# what is this function doing? replication

Tags: r, replication

```
rep_sample_n <- function(tbl, size, replace = FALSE, reps = 1)
{
rep_tbl = replicate(reps, tbl[sample(1:nrow(tbl), size, replace = replace), 
], simplify = FALSE) %>%
bind_rows() %>%
mutate(replicate = rep(1:reps, each = size)) %>%
select(replicate, everything()) %>%
group_by(replicate)
return(rep_tbl)
}
```

Hey, can anyone help me there? What is this function doing? Is the first line setting the variables of the function? And then what is this "replicate" doing? Thanks!

Comment: @Xbeanbi - Upvoted you for working with us here by removing the image and posting the code itself.  Yes the StackOverflow community can help. Please complete the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and update your post with resources to documentation (after going through that documentation if you still can't answer your question then its a good fit for a post on StackOverflow. Also, really clean posts typically get a far stronger response from the community (e.g, good grammar, properly formatted (including the appropriate indentation and spacing in code blocks). Welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function takes a data frame as input (and several input preferences). It takes a random sample of `size` rows from the table, with or without replacement as set by the `replace` input. It repeats that random sampling `reps` times.

Then, it binds all the samples together into a single data frame, adding a new column called "replicate" indicating which repetition of the sampling produced each row.

Finally, it "groups" the resulting table, preparing it for future group-wise operations with `dplyr`.

---

For general questions about specific functions, like *"What is this "replicate" doing?"*, you should look at the function's help page: type `?replicate` or `help("replicate")` to get there. It includes a description of the function and examples of how to use it. If you read the description, run the examples, and are still confused, feel free to come back with a specific question and example illustrating what you are confused by.

Similarly, for *"Is the first line setting the variables of the function?"*, the arguments to `function()` are the inputs to the function. If you have basic questions about R like "How do functions work", have a look at [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html), or one of the other sources in the  [R Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Answer (score 1):

This formula replicates your data. lets say we have a dataset of 10 observations. In order to come up with additional like-datasets of your current one, you can replicate it by introducing random sampling of your dataset.

You can check out the wikipedia page on 
[statistical replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(statistics)) if you're more curious.

Lets take a simple dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

df
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

if we want to take a random sample of this, we can use the function `rep_sample_n` which takes 2 arguments `tbl, size`, and has another 2 optional arguments `replace = FALSE, reps = 1`.

Here is an example of us just taking 4 randomly selected columns from our data.

```
rep_sample_n(df, 4)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   replicate [1]
  replicate     x     y
      <int> <int> <int>
1         1     1     1
2         1     3     3
3         1     4     4
4         1    10    10
```

Now if we want to randomly sample 15 observations from a 10 observation dataset, it will throw an error. Currently the `replace = FALSE` argument doesn't allow that because each time a sample row is chosen, it's removed from the pool for the next sample to be taken. In the example above, it chose the 1st observation, then it went to choose the 2nd (because we asked for 4), and it only have 2 through 10 left, and it chose the 3rd, then 4th and then 10th etc. If we allow `replace = TRUE`, it will choose an observation from the full dataset each time.

Notice how in this example, the 5th observation was chosen twice. That wouldn't happen with `replace = FALSE`

```
rep_sample_n(df, 4, replace = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   replicate [1]
  replicate     x     y
      <int> <int> <int>
1         1     5     5
2         1     3     3
3         1     2     2
4         1     5     5
```

Lastly and most importantly, we have the `reps` argument which is the basis for this function, really. It allows you randomly sample your dataset multiple times, and then combine all those samples together.

Below, we have sampled our original dataset of 10 observations by selecting 4 of them in a sample, then we replicated that 5 times, so we have 5 different sample dataframes of 4 observations each that have been combined together into one 20 observation dataframe, but each of the unique 5 dataframes has been tagged with a replicate #. The replicate column will point out which 4 observations goes with which replicated dataframe.

```
rep_sample_n(df, 4, reps = 5)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   replicate [5]
   replicate     x     y
       <int> <int> <int>
 1         1     8     8
 2         1     4     4
 3         1     3     3
 4         1     1     1
 5         2     4     4
 6         2     5     5
 7         2     8     8
 8         2     3     3
 9         3     6     6
10         3     1     1
11         3     3     3
12         3     2     2
13         4     5     5
14         4     7     7
15         4    10    10
16         4     3     3
17         5     7     7
18         5    10    10
19         5     3     3
20         5     9     9
```

I hope this provided some clarity